# Как создать новый проект в существующем решении в Visual Studio на Mac?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2017

Как создать новый проект в существующем решении в Visual Studio на Mac?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects

Comment: Да, спасибо, ходила сюда, прежде чем задать вопрос, но здесь указано, что это возможно, а вот как? Я правильно понимаю, если я уже создала проект и решение в Visual Studio и мне нужно создать еще один проект в том же решении, я иду в File->New Solution(т.к. только там есть опция создания New Project) и при попытке указать уже существующий Solution, в который мне нужно добавить проект, система выдает, что такой Solution уже существует и предлагает перезаписать его

Comment: контекстное меню Solution посмотрите (в винде это правой кнопкой мыши, не знаю, как там в маке), я думаю, там должно быть создание проекта.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, есть в контекстном солюшена)

Answer (score 1):

Свойства проекта (Solution) - добавить (Add) и выбирайте "новый проект"

[image: Добавление нового проекта]

Comment: Дада, спасибо!)